# Trouble setting up facebook login

Tags: javascript, android, ios, facebook, cordova

I am building a hybrid mobile app based out of JavaScript, CSS and HTML. I am using the *Intel XDK* to develop and deploy the app.

For Facebook integration I am using the following third party [plugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin) to work it out.

My aim is to get it to work both on iOS and Android. I have done the followings:

```
 <button onclick="fblogin()"> Login </button>
```

Script:

```
  <script>
    function fblogin() {    
    var fbLoginSuccess = function (userData) {
        alert("UserInfo: " + JSON.stringify(userData));
    }
    facebookConnectPlugin.login(Array strings of permissions, Function success, Function failure);


    facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile"],
        fbLoginSuccess,
        function (error) { alert("" + error) }
    );

    }

        </script>
```

The issues:
I have already enabled the plugin with my javascript api on the intel xdk.
fblogin() not defined at the following line:

```
facebookConnectPlugin.login(Array strings of permissions, Function success, Function failure);
```

I have read through the guide but is still confused. I would appreciate if someone could give me a step by step guide on making this work.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to look at the sample code on the README (https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin#sample-code)

You can write your function like this:

```
function fblogin() {
    var fbLoginSuccess = function (userData) {
        alert("UserInfo: " + JSON.stringify(userData));
    }

    facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile"],
        fbLoginSuccess,
        function (error) { alert("" + error) }
    );
}
```

i.e remove the
    `facebookConnectPlugin.login(Array strings of permissions, Function success, Function failure)`
line.